# Informations about JHipster Registry

Tags: jhipster

General questions :

- Can JHipster Registry work with a monolith application ?
- If yes how to configure it ? I did not understand the documentation on this point.
- How to get the JWT token ? If we don't use this authentication.

Answer (score 2):

So I found by myself some answers, yes it works with a monolith application all you need to do is to change the .yo-rc.json and write 
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",

Then regenerate your application and it should work now